# set autoincremental serial number in php

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

I am working on PHP using Kohana 3.2.I am displaying large number of data from database.I want to set the serial no from 1,2 upto the n-numbers depend on the number of data i am showing.I want to show the data in sequence.How to handle it through program.I can echo the total number of data(count) in page.

I don't know how to handle it in program.Need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it depends on whether you want to save the number or not, I guess.

If you do want to save it, create a field that will store the number and use `AUTO_INCREMENT`, read about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html).

If you don't need it to be stored, well, just echo a variable that increases itself. Something like this.

```
$i = 0;
foreach($data as $value){
   echo $i . ": " . $value;
   $i++; 
}
```

Mind, this is just a simple, basic code to give you an idea on how to do it.